# CS Cart Specific price per user group

Tags: php, cs-cart

Is it possible to add second price to each product and use that price if user in specific usergroup?

I was thinking doing that by adding another column to the product price table and then take advantage of the promotion function to somehow use that price instead of the usual discount you can set from admin.

Any pointers or ideas would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to define price for product that is valid/shown only for users in specific usergroup.

To achieve this you need to use **Quantity discounts** tab on **Editing product** page.

Name of this tab implies as there must be some large amount of items bought (like volume discounts...), but quantity can also be just 1 item.

For this you first need to define usergroup (Customers->User groups).

Example is shown also on CS-Cart Knowledge base: [Wholesale Prices](http://kb.cs-cart.com/wholesale-prices)

Best regards,
   Bostjan

Answer (score 0):

It is default CS-Cart feature. Please check the following article in the database:

http://kb.cs-cart.com/wholesale-prices